# Web Service Call - Error

Tags: c#, web-services, xsd

I've referenced a third party service reference and it created .svcinfo, .svcmap and couple of .xsd files.

In my code I've created a proxy of this service and tried to call a method `CreateAccount`(with values). After calling this method I got the following error:

> The top XML element 'OrderItems' from namespace 'https://www.mysite.com/MyOrder' references distinct types APITest.ServiceReference1.OrderItems and APITest.ServiceReference1.OtherOrderItems. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element or types.

I was able to call this method using SOAPUI tool and got a valid result from the service saying the account is created and it returned me the account number.

I'm using  Visual Studio , c#/vb , windows forms app to reference this service.

I did do a lot of search and didn't get the right answer to solve this error. Any Idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried checking your serialization in the proxy class.

[The XML element named 'name' from namespace references distinct types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532271/the-xml-element-named-name-from-namespace-references-distinct-types)

Comment: I've gone through this example earlier, after your refernce again today I've gone through the reference.cs file and modified one by one of the orderitems and it worked. Thanks!!